# Checking of input, Compatablity vs. Rigour

Tags: parsing, validation, networking, input

When parsing and validating input, two dicta are in tension with each other.

1. Check everything for safety.  Don't allow garbage in, because it can lead to who knows what out.
2. Be permissive about accepting input (but strict about producing output), because otherwise you are creating unnecessary incompatibilities.

What principle decides which rule to apply?  My best guess is that (1) applies to cases where you are validating data that will be passed on elsewhere.  Is there any other consideration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that #1 applies more to the content of the input (is it really a person's name, or is it a DROP TABLE command?), while #2 applies more to the format of the input (almost-valid XML -- we know what you mean, so we'll accept it).

I also think that various situations in which #2 was implemented (accepting poor HTML or XML; allowing javascript without semicolons for line endings) have proved to be mistakes.

Comment: Can you clarify your second point? What is a clue that what you think is a good application of #2 is an error?  Is it because it subtly allowed dodgy content; or is it a "social" mistake because it encouraged users to send dodgy input.

Comment: The latter; allowing poor HTML was widely adopted in the early days of the web, and the result was a lot of crappy HTML.  Better to draw the line early.  In my opinion, of course.  As far as what would be a clue... certainly any input that become part of potentially permanent infrastructure (a website, a web service) should be held to a higher standard than a temporary input (the input to a web form).